# Why Doctrine 2 not have basic validate method that validate if all values fit entities attributes?

Tags: orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, datamapper

I am new with doctrine 2.

**Why Doctrine 2 not have basic validate method that validate if all values fit entities attributes?**

My question target to understand more how doctrine 2 works and why without say that something wrong in doctine 2. (Mostly because i am new i miss some understanding about doctrine 2 way of design)

**Example:**

```
<?php
// entities/User.php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 **/
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $name;

}
```

code example of use of build in validate(not need connect to db, only validate @Column(type="integer") ) basic function that not exist in doctrine 2:

```
$user=new User();
$user->setId('trtr');
$user->setName("goodname");
if($user->validate()){
  echo 'ok';
}
else{
  echo $user->validateError();
}

//output: id of User should be integer and not string
```

Thanks

Comment: have a look here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-validations.html

Comment: I looked before i ask the question in  doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-validations.html. But no build in validate method in doctrine only custom method that not use entities attributes definitions. Or i miss something?

Comment: there is no built-in validation indeed.

Comment: soo i asking why? if entities attribute define the columns type etc.. why not to use them to basic validation?

Comment: We won’t ship Doctrine 2 with any validators, the reason being that we think all the frameworks out there already ship with quite decents ones that can be integrated into your Domain easily. Besides us being ORM experts not wanting to maintain yet another validation library, moving the responsibility of validation into the domain layer also allows you to integrate it much easier into frameworks form libraries for example.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html is one of these 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Why not to use entities for basic validation instead write validation code twice?if want more then basic then it can be done with custom validate function that will do more then entities attr validation as it already exist in doctrine 2 and in that custom dunction can be use third part software

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine ORM assumes that entities you're persisting are in a valid state. That's the only job of the persistence layer, and adding validation to it would just be wrong. If you have entities with invalid data in them, you already have an invalid object graph that should not be saved.

So please keep in mind that if you ever had some API like

```
$someEntity->isValid();
```

Then something is probably wrong, since the entity should always be valid, and any dependencies of it should be set at construction time and handled in setters/getters so that the object never reaches an inconsistent state.

Comment: To expand on this, data validation should normally be performed in your controller(s). A good example of this for your specific use-case is how Symfony 2 performs data validation using the Form component.  http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html  Thusly using `$form->isValid`rather than `$entity->isValid()` while allowing you to specify custom constraints for validation, keeping the Entity object code cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is separation of concerns.  Since entities are fairly dumb objects that don't know much about the rest of the world, their ability to do validations is limited to begin with.

For instance, there's no way that your typical entity could validate that a particular property is unique.

That said, if you just want to do basic validations, just do them in the setters.

```
<?php
class MyEntity {

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length="32")
     */
     protected $myProperty;

     public function setMyProperty($prop){
         if (! is_string($prop))
             throw new \InvalidArgumentException('MyEntity::setMyProperty() expects a string!';
         if (strlen($prop) > 32)
             throw new \LengthException('Argument passed to MyEntity::setMyProperty() is too long!');
         $this->myProperty = $prop;
     }

}
```

This approach can be used to enforce data types, lengths, etc.  Anything beyond that is better handled somewhere other than inside your entity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to mix entity and validation, but it make sense to have this rules in entity as annotation and validation logic in separated aspect validator class.

Check how it's done in Spring framework - 
http://www.abtosoftware.com/blog/form-validation-using-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-spring-framework

and how to implement it with doctrine2 and go -
http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/07/21/implementing-logging-aspect-with-doctrine-annotations/